# Unsupervised de-duping - potential matches not ordered by weight score descending?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I've got contacts that share Last Name and Email, and I'm using an unsupervised de-duping rule for online contribution forms and event registrations with the following fields and weights -

Email 10
Last Name 10
First Name 5
Threshold - 20

From testing, it looks like the matching logic is to go for the first qualify match, rather than ordering all qualify matches by 'score' based on matching fields. Am I wrong, or should there be a simple fix to order the weight of each match before deciding which contact to update that would greatly unsupervised matching?

You could then add additional fields with weight values that wouldn't contribute to threshold, but would improve the score of the best matching contact.